# Rafter above location for light, exterior light box choice

Tags: electrical, wiring, retrofit

[image]Retrofitting from knob and tube. One location has a rafter directly above where the light should go (and currently is). The ceiling is 3/4 in beadboard. Can I use a 4 inch pan box cut in to the beadboard, and then a junction box above and next to the rafter for the wiring? Should the bottom of the pan box be flush to the bottom of beadboard?  [image]

Answer (score 2):

### I'd use a *saddle box* instead

Instead of trying to cobble together something out of two different boxes, raising issues of access to the upper box, I would use a *saddle box* that fits around the rafter instead, as shown below (photo for exposition only).  This provides adequate space for splicing while allowing easy access to all the wiring here just by dropping the fixture.

[image: plastic saddle box]

Comment: The saddle box is usually proposed for hanging a fan. It looks like it does not have threaded holes for mounting a light fixture. You would need one of those metal "strap fixture mounts" that would have threaded screw holes. The strap would be secured by wood screws through the holes in the saddle box into the joist. It could work and would have much more volume than a pancake box.

Comment: Thanks very much for this idea.  Unfortunately since this is a c. 1910 home the lumber used in not quite like today.  The 2x4 is actually 2" x 4" for this rafter, so I would have to hack the rafter some to used this one as I assume it's designed for 1.5" lumber.  But it was very helpful as I started searching for this type of fan box and found another style which mounts next to just one side of the rafter, and I think that should work.  Will post below.

Comment: What is above the beadboard? Is there room for a person to work in the space above the joists? What is the height of the joists? The fan box which mounts on the side of a joist *may* require a deep joist (2x6 or even larger).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use another box behind a pancake box. The pancake box is low volume but it has enough volume for a single cable to connect to a light fixture.

You could cut a hole in the beadboard and mount the pancake box to the joist or you could surface mount the pancake box on the beadboard and mount the fixture to that. The edge of the pancake box is only 1/2 inch will not show very much. You could minimize that by painting the edge the same color as the beadboard.

Comment: I curious why one could not use another junction box with a feed to the pancake box?

Comment: Certainly one could use such a box, but the box would have to be exposed (with a cover) so it could be accessed without removal of the pancake box. It could not be behind the pancake box, covered by the pancake box.

Comment: You could use another box up in the attic space if it is accessible. The box would open up or out into the attic and would normally have a cover on it. You would do this if you had a junction of two or more wires that would take up more space than could be accommodated in a pancake box. Also this would provide a source for power for future wiring in the attic space.

Comment: Is the wiring to the fixture just going to be one cable? (This one cable would have neutral, switched hot, and ground.)  If so, it could be fit in a pancake box.

Comment: Thanks Jim for all your answers!  I think I'll be using the junction box.  Posting a separate answer as i wrote to much here.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your comments.  Not enough time to get right back to you.  Wish I had stated in the first post that there is an attic and it is accessible.  For most of the lights I had planned on using a Carlon old work box. B618R.  For several reasons I was just going to run power (14/2) between each light box and drop a single 14/2 romex to each switch. Fishing the wire to each switch isn't that easy, so It just make sense to run the power light to light in the attic. Yes the pancake box will be accessible from the home and the junction box for this one light accessible in the attic.  There is a ton of blown in insulation that I've cleared away at each of the old lights and switch areas.  So each light box will have power coming and going and the wire to the light. So I calculate 6 wires x 2, plus ground wires, plus internal clamps = 6 + 1 + 1= 8 * 2" = 16in   The box is 18 in3.  But for the one described above I will have a junction box maybe mounted on top of the joist then run the single switched power romex to the pancake box mounted on the joist.   I saw another box that can mount partially on the side of the joist, but it's only 12 cubic inches, to I can't make up the connections inside it anyway.
I guess the other questions are about protecting the romex and if the one (or more) junction boxes I use gets covered with insulation.  The way I understand it within 6-7 ft of the attic access the wiring should be protected (no permanent stairs or ladder).  And I don't think it matters if anything gets covered with insulation as long as it's accessible if one moved away the insulation.  I'll obviously map out the install and might even put some colored flags hanging from the rafters where the lighting/junction boxes are.

[image]

Comment: Now I see the Carlon B618R (with wings) isn't rated for a fixture when installed in a ceiling.  All my locations have the solid wood beadboard, so obviously stronger than sheetrock, but I guess I can't really use them in the ceiling in any case.  Back to the drawing board.